# SSL certificate issue in feign client spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, ssl

So I have written a feign client which is supposed to send https call to another service, but it still issue.

**Error log**

> "2024-03-15T06:22:34.609383652Z stderr F [xApi#getSomething] javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

here is the bean of my client

```
    @Bean
    fun xApi(): XApi {
        val m =  createFeignBuilder(
            config.connectionTimeoutInMs,
            config.readTimeoutInMs,
        )
            // no need to add hostnameVerifier
            .client(Client.Default(buildSSLSocketFactory(config.keyStore), NoopHostnameVerifier()))
            .contract(Contract.Default())
        return m.target(XApi::class.java, config.url)
    }
```

and

```
    private fun buildSSLSocketFactory(keyStore: Keystore): SSLSocketFactory? {
        return if (keyStore.filePath.isNullOrBlank() || keyStore.password.isNullOrBlank() ) {
            null // if there is no keystore provided, no custom ssl factory should be added
        } else {
            logger.info("Using ${keyStore.filePath} file for ssl socket")
            val keyStorePassword = keyStore.password.toCharArray()
            val keyStoreFile = keyStore.filePath
            SSLContextBuilder.create().loadKeyMaterial(File(keyStoreFile), keyStorePassword, keyStorePassword)
                .build().socketFactory
        }
    }
```

I have tried almost everything possible, I can't logs or errors or anything. Im kinf of lost here

Comment: Hi. What is your os? Can you use a nginx or apache instead of direct ssl usage?